# Prevent fake locations on Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to detect if the user is using a Fake Location app. I'm not talking about mock locations, I'm talking about the users with rooted phones, that can fake gps location without using the mock locations setting.

I know a solution is to check NMEA data, because most fake location apps don't send NMEA information, but this solution is not working on all phones and I want a solution that works for all the users.

Is there a better way to check fake locations that I didn't found? Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use IP or base station to help you check fake location.

Answer (score 1):

I also interested about problem, I would like to know how to compare different between true-location & fake-location.

Now I limit fake location by the way:

- Receive broadcast fake-application was installed. (We can recognize fake-app by it used permission mock_location)
- We can not use location until fake-app uninstall.